# How do I show two related select tag values from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

The easiest example is when you pick a country from select tag and the other select tag will automatically show the city/states based on the selected country.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use either javascript or jquery

Here an example of jquery:

In your js file:

```
$("#product").on("change",function(){
    var temp = $(this).val();

    if(temp != ''){
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "product="+temp+",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "ajax.php",
            success: function(data){
             output city here
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically that's not simply php. In most cases it has to do with JavaScript and AJAX.

At least if you want this to happen without a reload.

Easiest way would be to automatically perform a submit on your form if the first select is changed. And the perform a MySQL query and a loop to output the corresponding values in select 2. 
With AJAX the same would run smoother as it does not rely on a reload.

You can as well store all needed data within a json object inside the browser and rebuild the select if needed. Might be the easiest way.

All solutions mentioned above require JavaScript in some way

Answer (score 0):

You would start with the the two select tags, the country box and the states box on the original page. Once the a country has been selected, i.e. javascript event change, then you want to fire off an ajax request. The ajax request would POST the country id to a new php file, the php file would use the county id to look up the states from that country through mysql. It would then return the request and you would create the state select box. ORDER BY name, and contain the value of the state id.

Then you echo this select box, and bring this data back to the original page through the ajax call. Insert it to replace the previous de-activated sate box, and make sure it is now activated.

If the page is refreshed then this state select box would revert back to de-activated, unless you have a session that also sets through the ajax like e.g. $_SESSION['country'], and the original page would first check if this set, if it is, display the country as selected, along with their corresponding states.